# is there a way to open and edit word file in android?

Tags: android

and if this application exist does it has an open API?

Comment: I highly doubt there exists an application with *both* of those criteria. What I would do is shoehorn the .doc functionality of OpenOffice into an android app.  I'm not sure what the parser is written in but it's most likely either C++ or Java or some combination of both.  Both of which will run on Android.

Answer (score 1):

nop theres no API to support that, and this is the only way that I Know

[Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Adobe PDF files on your Android-powered Smartphone](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/)

Answer (score 1):

An app like QuickOffice or Documents To Go comes on every Android I've seen. If it already has the app then the following should work: [Android Launching an application chooser with appropriate list of applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497350/android-launching-an-application-chooser-with-appropriate-list-of-applications)