# how to open MS word,ppt and excel document in android2.2 emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an android 2.2 application. I want to open MS word,ppt and excel files to be open in emulator. How can I achieve it? is there any free version of Documents To Go?

Please help

Thanks
Parvendra

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer to an answer: [Android Launching an application chooser with appropriate list of applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497350/android-launching-an-application-chooser-with-appropriate-list-of-applications)