# How to Open Documents in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, so i have a question regarding how to open any document such as .doc, .docx, .ppt, etc. in android. I also need to implement preview functionality, wherein the file should be downloaded temporarily and user can see the file opened just by a single click.

How does dropbox does this? Is there any intents available?

Can anybody help me out of this issue by some example or code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike iOS, Android itself does not support rendering .doc or .ppt files.
You are looking for a public intent that allows your app to reuse other apps' activities to display these document types. But this will only work for a phone that has an app installed that supports this Intent.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Android Launching an application chooser with appropriate list of applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497350/android-launching-an-application-chooser-with-appropriate-list-of-applications)